# jstl if-else loop perameter passing

Tags: java, jstl

i am using jstl.

How can i use parameter for test case.

```
<c:when test="${myBean.method=='1'}">

</c:when>
```

i want to pass perameter in method like

```
<c:when test="${myBean.method('para')=='1'}">

</c:when>
```

Comment: can you try ... myBean.method("para") ... ?  // change ' on "

Comment: i got following error. javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /consumer/HomePage.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 11] Element type "c:when" must be followed by e
ither attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:425)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:408)

Answer (score -1):

You could call a function with a parameter in JSTL 2.0. But for that you should create a TLD like on below:

```
<function>
   <name>method</name>
   <function-class>MyBean</function-class>
   <function-signature>
      java.lang.String method(java.lang.String)
   </function-signature>
 </function>
```

Then you could access

```
<c:when test="${cx:method('para')} eq '1'}">
</c:when>
```

Go through this link for complete example.[JSTL 2.0 Example](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2003/jw-0523-calltag.html?page=2)

Comment: You must have to define your method public static otherwise will not work in this way..

Comment: i am getting error like javax.el.ELException: Function 'x:getMethod' not found
        at org.apache.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.visit(ExpressionBuilder.java:175)
        at org.apache.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:145)
        at org.apache.el.parser.SimpleNode.accept(SimpleNode.java:148)

Comment: Did you try marking the method as static as @user1270995 said?

Comment: yes i did. my method is public static String getMethod(String s1){}